# Jquery Chain select script from database

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter

Please help me fix this script for my application , I am trying to get a chain select working.
The script basically checks for the selected dropdown value from dropdown and search the database for the value

**JS:**

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
    $("#propinsi_id").change(function () {
        var propinsi_id = {
            propinsi_id: $("#propinsi_id").val()
        };
        $.Ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo SITE_URL('Repair/select_fault')?>",
            Data: propinsi_id,
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#city').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
</Script>
```

**ERROR:**

```
I caught this error 

Uncaught TypeError: Object
function (selector, context) {
    //The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);
}
has no method 'Ajax'
```

Comment: use ajax instead of Ajax (see case)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$.Ajax({
```

Needs to be lower case

```
$.ajax({
```

I would also change `Data:` to `data:`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $("#propinsi_id").change(function(){
                var  propinsi_id = {propinsi_id:$("#propinsi_id").val()};
                $.ajax({ //<---here
                        type: "POST" ,
                        url: "<?php echo SITE_URL('Repair/select_fault')?>" ,
                        data:propinsi_id, //<---here
                        success:function(msg) {
                            $('#city').html(msg);
                        }
                    });
        });

 </script>
```